# in powershell, is there a way to check if the path is valid regardless deny access

Tags: powershell

In powershell, is there a way to check if the path is valid regardless deny access?

I ran into this problem when I tried to verify the UNC Path of \$ServerName\$ShareName using powershell cmdlet "test-path" (see code below).  The cmdlet will return "false" to the UNC path although the path does exist (but it has deny access group in place for the person who ran the "test-path").

```
test-path "\\$serverName\$shareName"
```

I need a way to check if the path exist or not regardless the deny access group in place.

Do you have one liner (or small block of codes) in powershell to resolve this?

Comment: You clearly can't do this. If access is specifically denied for a user, they have no access. Period. It would be totally useless to deny access if the user could then bypass that restriction to gain access. **No access** means **no access**, period. Why would you think **no access** means you can get access anyway?

Comment: @KenWhite I have no access to `\\server\accounts` but I can still open Explorer, browse to `\\server\` and see that it exists. Seeing that a thing exists is not the same as being able to get into it. (Although in my case, Test-Path verifies it as a True path, so the permissions must be different to Liang Cui's situation).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: You can verify that the server exists, but if you've been denied access to that server you cannot see if a folder exists on that server. There's a big difference. If there wasn't, there wouldn't be much network security. I'm a domain admin for an AD OU, and I can see other servers in the domain that are not in my OU, but I can't browse the folders on those servers.

Comment: @KenWhite as TessellatingHeckler already explained, I need to know the path exist or not even I don't have the access. I don't wish to see what's inside from the path. I just wish to know if it is exist in powershell script.

Comment: And as *I* already explained, you **cannot do this** because you have no access. I don''t know why that's so hard for you to understand - if you have no access, you can't do anything that requires access. It's not rocket science - **you can't go here because you're not allowed** means **you can't go here because you're not allowed**. It doesn't mean **but you can go here anyway, even though you've been told you're not allowed**.

Comment: Aside from all this, what problem does this solve, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. The code below will give correct boolean value after try catch script blocks.

- When the $path is invalid, test-path will not give error and return
  FALSE.
- When the $path is valid and user has access, test-path will return
  TRUE.
- When the $path is valid and user has no access, test-path will throw
  an error (test-path : Access is denied), and catch script will force
  the boolean value to be TRUE.

Example:

```
[boolean]$PathExist = $False
Try { $PathExist = Test-Path $path -ErrorAction Stop }
Catch { 
    if($_.Exception.Message -eq 'Access is Denied'){
        $PathExist = $True
    }
    else {
        $PathExist = $False
    }
}
```

Comment: If you test `\\$serverName\$shareName\subfolder` but do not have access to the parent `shareName` how can you truly be sure the target folder exists (or not), when the error is thrown on the parent?

Comment: The purpose is to scan the file share level only, and find out if the file share exist or not in the enterprise. 
It doesn't need to go to subfolder.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: it is a tool that I created. I don't want the test-path give "FALSE" if the path does exist (but you don't have the access).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Why does it matter whether the path exists?

Comment: My working environment sometimes involve file shares that has special access at the share level. There is no single account that have the access to the entire enterprise file shares due to the varies of special access (it is good to have that for security measure). So, if I want to scan the entire file shares with single account, this code will allow me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, in order to view the folders you at least need Traverse Folder for your user account, or for a group you are in, then you would be able to do a test-path, however if you didn't have read attributes on the files within those folders, you'd still only see the folders that you are allowed to access/view.